# Google maps dynamic marker design

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

Hello,

is it possible to create such a customized marker on google maps. (See the image)
There would be plenty of markers on the map, the image link would come from the database and I'd give a colour code for the arrow.
Is it possible to create the coloured arrow from javascript code and use a link for the image in the middle?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the API docs for custom markers? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Answer (score 2):

You can change the image of a marker by using this code:

```
image = 'images_url/image_name.png';
marker = {map:map, icon:image, etc};
```

but if you want to resize it, use an array variable as explained below;

```
ico= {
     image: 'url and imagename',
     size: new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
     }

    marker = {map:map,icon:ico, etc};
```